# Best API URL naming for a model with 2 belongTo relations

Tags: rest, naming

I have a model named Booking with a User, a Service and the createdAt fields.

The URL to create a new Booking should be:

- [POST] /bookings?user_id={user_id}&service_id={service_id}
  or
- [POST] /users/{user_id}/bookings?service_id={service_id}
  or
- [POST] /services/{service_id}/bookings?user_id={user}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those are *fine*, but....

It's a good idea to pay attention to cache invalidation.  The target URI of your request is one of three resource identifiers that will be automatically invalidated by a successful POST request.  You can take advantage of that to evict a web page in the client's cache whose information will be changed by the message you send.

For example, if creating a new booking adds a new link to the `/bookings` resource, then

```
POST /bookings
```

has the advantage of automatically evicting the previously cached copy of the resource that doesn't include the link you just created.